# Interpretation of Multilevel Mediation

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, mediation

I am attempting to perform a multilevel mediation and found this page online with an example:

https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-perform-mediation-with-multilevel-data-method-2/

It follows a method laid out in a paper by Bauer et al. (2006): Bauer, D. J., Preacher, K. J. & Gil, K. M. (2006) Conceptualizing and testing random indirect effects and moderated mediation in multilevel models: New procedures and recommendations. Psychological Methods, 11(2), 142-163.

By following the instructions in the webpage, I was able to replicate the structure with my own data, but I'm confused regarding how to interpret the output of the "stacked" mediation model they ran. Do the fixed effects here translate directly to what we would call the direct and indirect effects in a traditional mediation analysis? If so, which of the terms in the output correspond to which effect?

To add another wrinkle into this, in my own dataset, I have a potential moderator that could act on the path from the IV to the mediator as well as on the path from the mediator to the DV. Using this structure, how would I test this in lme4, if at all possible? Is there another package in R that would be more appropriate for this analysis?

Comment: I am not familiar with the approach in Bauer et al. I suggest looking into Tingley et al's mediation package in R (https://imai.fas.harvard.edu/research/files/mediationR2.pdf). It allows you to run mediation on lme4 models and it also has additional sensitivity tests that deal with the causal assumptions of mediation.